# JetBrains Rider XAML preview not available

Tags: c#, xaml, jetbrains-ide, rider

[I can't find the menu option under JetBrains Rider menus.](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/03/29/xaml-preview-tool-window-wpf-rider/)
[image]

I have a XAML file open and can't find the option under View > Tool Windows.
[My project is a WPF, .NET Core 3.1 application](https://github.com/lsoares/yeelight-remote-control).

I'm running Rider 2020.1.3 Build #RD-201.7846.1 on Windows 10 (Licensed):

[image]
[image]

What am I missing? Is it because this is .NET Core and not .NET Framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rider does not support XAML preview for .NET Core projects at this time.

This is related issue in the tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-35773

I hope it will be implemented any time soon =)